# Calculate mean over grouped lines

Tags: awk, mean

I have a set of files which following information:

```
 ID      Score    Other
 ABR     0.98     NBNMSB
 BCG     0.76     NBNMSB
 CVD     0.6      NBNMSB
 BCG     0.9      VSCVA
 CVD     0.56     VSCVA
 ABR     0.9      VSCVA
 CVD     0.7      BAVSC
 BCG     0.4      BAVSC
 ABR     0.5      BAVSC
 ABR     0.8      NBNMSB
 BCG     0.6      NBNMSB
 CVD     0.3      NBNMSB
 BCG     0.7      VSCVA
 CVD     0.0      VSCVA
 ABR     0.1      VSCVA
 CVD     0.5      BAVSC
 BCG     0.8      BAVSC
 ABR     1.0      BAVSC
```

I want to calculate the max of scores across first column i.e the ID for each of the third column such that the result would be grouped by first column and the max of score would be calculated for third column as follows:

File ABR.txt

```
 ABR     0.98    NBNMSB
 ABR     0.9     VSCVA
 ABR     1.0     BAVSC
```

File BCG.txt

```
 BCG     0.76     NBNMSB
 BCG     0.9      VSCVA
 BCG     0.8      BAVSC
```

and same for CVD exceot that the files are really large and multiple such files, currently I am using following code:

while read ID;do

```
 while read line; do
  block=$(echo $line | awk '{print $1}')
  max_of_score=$(grep $block Negative/fileofinterest*.ext | grep $ID | awk 'BEGIN {max = 0} {if ($2>max) max=$2} END {print max}')
  echo $block $max_of_score >> $ID"_max.txt"
 done < fileOfcolumn3values.txt
 #contains all the possible values of column 3 (in this case NBNMSB, VSCVA, BAVSC)
done < fileOfIdscolumn1.txt
#contains all possible values of column 1 (in this case ABR, BCG, CVD)
```

I would like to find a possible code that would work faster than the above algorithm, TIA

Comment: Your question is unclear. You say you have a set of files containing some set of information which you include an example of. Then you list 2 files. Are those sample input or expected output files? What's the correlation to the first set of data you posted? If they're input, what's the output? It sounds like you need something to work on multiple files so please post, say, 3 small sample input files and the expected output given those 3 input files. If the expected output is multiple files then state and show that.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this entirely in `awk`

```
awk '{
     if (($1, $3) in a)
     {
      if ($2 > a[$1, $3]) a[$1, $3] = $2
     } 
     else a[$1, $3] = $2
     };
    END
    {
    for (x in a)
    {
     split(x, b, SUBSEP); print b[1], a[x], b[2] > b[1]".txt"
    }
    }' file
```

This generates

```
cat ABR.txt
ABR 1.0 BAVSC
ABR 0.98 NBNMSB
ABR 0.9 VSCVA
```

and so on